# Changing allowed country after publishing android app

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my android app in Google Playstore by selecting few countries in Allowed countries section.

I selected few more countries after publishing the app, but the app is not showing up in
newly added countries after publishing

**(When user tried to install app from these newly added countries, it says "This app is not allowed in your device's country"**

Should i unpublish the app, and save the newly added countries settings and then publish?

is this the right way to do this?

Comment: "I selected few more countries after publishing the app, but its not actually enabled." - if it is not enabled, how you selected it in first place?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check.

Comment: You need to wait, let's say 2-3 hours. Before, this delay was much more smaller but now I can suggest you to be patient.

Comment: When did you make the changes that you have mentioned?

Comment: @SurajBajaj After hitting Publish, i made these new changes.

Comment: I meant how long has it been since you made changes?

Comment: even now i cannot see.. actually the i bough my device in China and using it in my Country.. will that be a problem? may be the country set to China.. not sure..

Comment: does that appears as an update to the users or it just updates it in the background without the user actually have to download the update ???